# Three.js: How do I get sharper shadows on MeshLambertMaterial?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, webgl

I'm working on some code to draw 3D images of the moon at various phases, showing libration effects as well. At this point, my image of a first quarter moon looks like this:

[image]

Which looks very nice, but the transition from light to shadow is too gradual. As there is no atmosphere on the moon, the transition from light to dark should be more abrupt.

This is the code I have so far:

```
  private drawMoonWebGL(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, solarSystem: SolarSystem, time_JDE: number,
           cx: number, cy: number, size: number, pixelsPerArcSec: number, pixelRatio: number,
           parallacticAngle?: Angle, observer?: ISkyObserver, _showEclipses?: boolean): void {
    if (!this.renderer)
      this.setUpRenderer();

    if (size === 0)
      size = MAX_LUNAR_ANGULAR_DIAMETER * pixelsPerArcSec * 60;

    if (this.webGlRendererSize !== size) {
      this.renderer.setSize(size, size);
      this.webGlRendererSize = size;
    }

    const phase = solarSystem.getLunarPhase(time_JDE);
    const libration = solarSystem.getLunarLibration(time_JDE, observer);

    this.camera.position.z = libration.D * KM_PER_AU;
    this.camera.rotation.z = (parallacticAngle ? parallacticAngle.radians : 0);
    this.globeMesh.rotation.y = to_radian(-libration.l);
    this.globeMesh.rotation.x = to_radian(libration.b);
    this.sun.position.x = 93000000 * sin_deg(phase); // Very rough, but adequate for the task!
    this.sun.position.z = -93000000 * cos_deg(phase);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    context.drawImage(this.renderer.domElement, cx - size / 2, cy - size / 2);
  }

  private setUpRenderer(): void {
    const globe = new SphereGeometry(MOON_RADIUS, 50, 50);

    globe.rotateY(-PI / 2);
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(MAX_LUNAR_ANGULAR_DIAMETER / 60, 1, 0.1, 500000);
    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.globeMesh = new Mesh(globe, new MeshLambertMaterial({ map: new CanvasTexture(this.moonImageForWebGL) }));
    this.scene.add(this.globeMesh);
    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
    this.sun = new DirectionalLight('white', 1.5);
    this.sun.position.y = 0;
    this.scene.add(this.sun);
    this.scene.add(new AmbientLight('white', 0.15));
  }
```

The above code takes an equirectangular moon map (courtesy of NASA) like this:

[image]

...and wraps it around a sphere so it can be rotated and illuminated in various ways.

With the searching for answers I've done so far I've only found information regarding one object casting shadows on a different object. I can't find anything about adjusting the shadows on a single object with a single main light source.

There's a little bit of ambient lighting added by my code (representing "earth shine") to make sure the shadowed part of the moon isn't pitch black, but removing that ambient lighting doesn't sharpen the shadow boundary very much at all.

Can anyone tell me what I should to adjust to get the sharper shadow boundaries I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out MeshPhongMaterial (which I'd avoided at first because I'd associated it with glossy objects and specular highlights) works better for me, with reflectivity and shininess set to zero.

More than that, however: `this.renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding` makes the image contrast and gamma much, much better.

Another small tweak on top of these other changes was to vary the degree of Earth shine from a maximum at new moon to a minimum at full moon (as it should be anyway).

[image]

```
  private drawMoonWebGL(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, solarSystem: SolarSystem, time_JDE: number,
           cx: number, cy: number, size: number, pixelsPerArcSec: number, pixelRatio: number,
           parallacticAngle?: Angle, observer?: ISkyObserver, _showEclipses?: boolean): void {
    if (!this.renderer)
      this.setUpRenderer();

    if (size === 0)
      size = MAX_LUNAR_ANGULAR_DIAMETER * pixelsPerArcSec * 60;

    if (this.webGlRendererSize !== size) {
      this.renderer.setSize(size, size);
      this.webGlRendererSize = size;
    }

    const phase = solarSystem.getLunarPhase(time_JDE);
    const libration = solarSystem.getLunarLibration(time_JDE, observer);

    this.camera.position.z = libration.D * KM_PER_AU;
    this.camera.rotation.z = (parallacticAngle ? parallacticAngle.radians : 0);
    this.globeMesh.rotation.y = to_radian(-libration.l);
    this.globeMesh.rotation.x = to_radian(libration.b);
    this.sun.position.x = 93000000 * sin_deg(phase);
    this.sun.position.z = -93000000 * cos_deg(phase);
    this.earthShine.intensity = 0.025 + cos_deg(phase) * 0.0125;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    context.drawImage(this.renderer.domElement, cx - size / 2, cy - size / 2);
  }

  private setUpRenderer(): void {
    const globe = new SphereGeometry(MOON_RADIUS, 50, 50);

    globe.rotateY(-PI / 2);
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(MAX_LUNAR_ANGULAR_DIAMETER / 60, 1, 0.1, 500000);
    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.globeMesh = new Mesh(globe, new MeshPhongMaterial({ map: new CanvasTexture(this.moonImageForWebGL),
      reflectivity: 0, shininess: 0 }));
    this.scene.add(this.globeMesh);
    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
    this.renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
    this.sun = new DirectionalLight('white', 1.5);
    this.sun.position.y = 0;
    this.scene.add(this.sun);
    this.earthShine = new AmbientLight('white');
    this.scene.add(this.earthShine);
  }
```